# Kubernetes (K3S) POD gets "ENOTFOUND" after 5-20 hours of airing time

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, k3s

I'm running my Backend on **Kubernetes** on around **250** pods under **15** deployments, backend in written in **NODEJS**.

Sometimes after X number of hours (5<X<30) I'm getting `ENOTFOUND` in one of the PODS, as follows:

```
{
  "name": "main",
  "hostname": "entrypoint-sdk-54c8788caa-aa3cj",
  "pid": 19,
  "level": 50,
  "error": {
    "errno": -3008,
    "code": "ENOTFOUND",
    "syscall": "getaddrinfo",
    "hostname": "employees-service"
  },
  "msg": "Failed calling getEmployee",
  "time": "2022-01-28T13:44:36.549Z",
  "v": 0
}
```

I'm running a stress test on the Backend of YY number of users per second, but I'm keeping this stress level steady and not changing it, and then it happens out of nowhere with no specific reason.

Kubernetes is **K3S** Server Version: **v1.21.5+k3s2**

Any idea what might cause this weird `ENOTFOUND`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already saw your [same question on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107866) and reference to [getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND with newest versions](https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets/issues/860).

As per comments this issue does not appear in k3s 1.21, that is 1 version below yours. I know it almost impossible, but any chance to try similar setup on this ver?

And it seems error comes from [node/lib/dns.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1125c8a814030f16fc995d897181ac9920f9d3db/lib/dns.js#L17-L24).

```
function errnoException(err, syscall, hostname) {
  // FIXME(bnoordhuis) Remove this backwards compatibility nonsense and pass
  // the true error to the user. ENOTFOUND is not even a proper POSIX error!
  if (err === uv.UV_EAI_MEMORY ||
      err === uv.UV_EAI_NODATA ||
      err === uv.UV_EAI_NONAME) {
    err = 'ENOTFOUND';
  }
```

What I wanted to suggest you is to check [Solving DNS lookup failures in Kubernetes](https://tech.findmypast.com/k8s-dns-lookup/). Article describes long hard way of catching the same error you have that also  bothered from time to time.

As a solution aftet investigating all the metrics, logs, etc - was installing   K8s cluster add-on called [Node Local DNS cache](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/nodelocaldns/), that

> improves Cluster DNS performance by running a dns
> caching agent on cluster nodes as a DaemonSet. In today's
> architecture, Pods in ClusterFirst DNS mode reach out to a kube-dns
> serviceIP for DNS queries. This is translated to a kube-dns/CoreDNS
> endpoint via iptables rules added by kube-proxy. With this new
> architecture, Pods will reach out to the dns caching agent running on
> the same node, thereby avoiding iptables DNAT rules and connection
> tracking. The local caching agent will query kube-dns service for
> cache misses of cluster hostnames(cluster.local suffix by default).
>
> Motivation
>
> - With the current DNS architecture, it is possible that Pods with the    highest DNS QPS have to reach out to a different node, if there
>   is no    local kube-dns/CoreDNS instance. Having a local cache will
>   help    improve the latency in such scenarios.
> - Skipping iptables DNAT and connection tracking will help reduce    conntrack races and avoid UDP DNS entries filling up conntrack table.
> - Connections from local caching agent to kube-dns service can be    upgraded to TCP. TCP conntrack entries will be removed on connection
>   close in contrast with UDP entries that have to timeout (default
>   nf_conntrack_udp_timeout is 30 seconds)
> - Upgrading DNS queries from UDP to TCP would reduce tail latency    attributed to dropped UDP packets and DNS timeouts usually up to 30s
>   (3 retries + 10s timeout). Since the nodelocal cache listens for UDP
>   DNS queries, applications don't need to be changed.
> - Metrics & visibility into dns requests at a node level.
> - Negative caching can be re-enabled, thereby reducing number of    queries to kube-dns service.

Comment: Thanks , first of all , for being the first that actually understands this crazy problem , there are not many like you! I've tried this `https://github.com/external-secrets/kubernetes-external-secrets/issues/860` , but it's a NO-HELP , I've upgraded all my K3S to version `1.22.3+k3s1` and still didn't help. I've already asked our DEVOPS to go ahead with the ` Node Local DNS cache` , but does it mean that K3S is not Production Ready ? Why the hell do I keep on getting this `ENOTFOUND` error ?